Method not calculating the Relative Strength
I am trying to calcuate the Relative strength of stock compared to the index. Both dataframes are csv. Following is the code -
class RSstrategy(Strategy):
def init(self):
pass
def calculate_relative_strength(self, stock_data, nifty_data, ma_period=50):
    stock_close = stock_data['Close']
    index_close = nifty_data['Close']
    rs_stgth = stock_close / index_close
    rs_rolling_mean = rs_stgth.rolling(window=30).mean()
    
    return rs_stgth, rs_rolling_mean

def next(self):
    stock_data = self.data.df
    nifty_data = RSstrategy.nifty_data
    
    rs, rs_mean = self.calculate_relative_strength(stock_data, nifty_data)

    # Store the current values of RS and RS mean
    self.rs.iloc[-1] = rs.iloc[-1]
    self.rs_mean.iloc[-1] = rs_mean.iloc[-1]
    
    
    if  (crossover(self.rs.iloc[-1], self.rs_mean.iloc[-1])):
        self.buy() 
    elif (crossover(self.rs_mean.iloc[-1], self.rs.iloc[-1])):
        self.position.close()

In the backtest the trades are not getting executed when there is a crossover.
After running - bt.run the trades should have gotten executed but the trades are not getting executed in the backtest
